# print 2 values from selected option that use mysql to popullate list

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a mysql connection working with a query.

```
<?php
$enlace = mysqli_connect ('localhost:3306',  'user', 'pass');

$consulta = "SELECT id, nameFROM dbapps.dbapp";
$result=mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta);
?>
```

I have a SELECT filled with 2 values.
Option value =ID 
the description = id + Name

```
<select name="sqllist[]" multiple> 
<?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<option value=" .$row['0'].">".$row['0']."  ".$row['1']."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

Im getting the selected value but i want to get the selected id with one variable and the name related to the id with other variable

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST['sqllist'] as $select)
    {
        echo $select."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Look up the name in the database.

Comment: Posting only sends the value of the option, not the text.

Comment: You could put the name in the value if you want, then use `explode(" ", $select)` to split it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Read all the results from the query
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all ( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Id/name map
$names = array_column($rows, 'name', 'id');

// If the data was submitted, use it, otherwise, consider the list empty
$sqllist = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['sqllist'] : [];

// Create the select statement
<select name="sqllist[]" multiple> 
<?php 
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    // If the id for this row is in the sqllist, set the selected attribute
    $selected = in_array($row['id'],$sqllist) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo "<option $selected value='" .$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."  ".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<?php
foreach ($sqllist as $id) {
    echo $id.' '.$names[$id].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it works better in that way, I echo the id  in one column and then query the app name:

$consulta2 = "SELECT AppName FROM dbapps.dbapp WHERE id= '{$id}'";

Thanks for your help